# Unexpected number in jquery variable

Tags: jquery

I want create a google map in website and create a variable file let user define the map location.

map.js

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(varLocation); // map location
```

var.js

```
var varLocation = 123.456789, 987.654321;
```

its show `Unexpected number` error in console.

How can i use this kind of number in variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for defining the `varLocation` is incorrect - it can only contain one value, hence the 'unexpected number' error. You need to define the values separately. Try this:

```
var latitude = 123.456789;
var longitude = 987.654321;

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

It's worth noting that the `LatLng()` method is, as it's name implies, execting latitude and longitude values to be provided. The numerical values you're providing are *well* beyond the limits of lat/lng extents an will not work correctly with a Google map.

Latitude can be from `-90` to `90`, and longitude goes from `-180` to `180`.